# Why can JDBC connect to MySQL when SSL has been configured, without having the cert

Tags: java, mysql, ssl, jdbc

My issue is I seem to have secured MySQL from the command line, yet when I connect through JDBC that same restriction falls away. I'm a beginner to using SSL for my database connection, this is the first time I've tried to set it up.

I setup SSL for MySQL locally on my Linux machine. I generated the certificates, editing my.cnf, etc.

Here is what I added to my my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
ssl-ca=/var/lib/mysql/cert/ca-cert.pem
ssl-cert=/var/lib/mysql/cert/server-cert.pem
ssl-key=/var/lib/mysql/cert/server-key.pem
```

Right there are valid paths to my server cert/key, and my CA cert. It's self-signed. I'll get to having a more official one when I need it.

In the MySQL database, I set my database user account to require SSL:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO ‘orgapi’@’localhost’
IDENTIFIED BY ‘password’ REQUIRE SSL;
```

So far so good. Once that user requires SSL, MySQL seems to require a client cert to be provided when making the connection. I generated that cert as well, signing it with the same self-signed CA cert.

Now, for the first test: I tried logging in from the command line WITHOUT the client cert:

```
mysql -u orgapi -p -h localhost
```

Voila, it fails to let me log in. However, when I include the SSL cert in the login command, like this:

`mysql --ssl-ca=ca-cert.pem --ssl-cert=client-cert.pem --ssl-key=client-key.pem -u orgapi -p -h localhost`

It works like a charm. I'm able to connect when I specify the client cert, and if I do a "status" command, it says I'm connected using SSL.

### The problem

To ensure that everything was all set to go, I threw together some basic test code using JDBC. Currently, I'm not providing the client certs to this JDBC code. Because of that, I would expect the connection to fail.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306", "orgapi", "orgapi");
        conn.setCatalog("org_app");
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery("select * from users");
        while(resultSet.next()){
            System.out.println(resultSet.getString(1) + " " + resultSet.getString(2));
        }
    }
```

What worries me is that it doesn't fail. In fact, it executes the query without any issue. Now, if I append to the end of the database url "?useSSL=true", then it will fail to connect because it doesn't have the cert. But it still concerns me that JDBC code would be able to connect to MySQL and bypass the restrictions that exist elsewhere.

So I'm just wondering what I may be doing wrong, or what I don't understand about this process. I just want to be sure that I'm not leaving my database less secure somehow.

### Edit

I do get this interesting log message when I'm using JDBC:

> Sun Oct 23 08:58:28 EDT 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without
> server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL
> 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance
> with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate
> property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL
> by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for
> server certificate verification.

Comment: From the JDBC connection without SSL, run the query `SHOW GRANTS;`.  Compare the response to the result you get for that same query when using the cli with SSL.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot they seem to be the same. Neither says anything about SSL, they simply say "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'orgapi'@'localhost'". I added a log entry I'm seeing from JDBC to the post above, if that helps at all.

Comment: Have you considered setting `verifyServerCertificate` to true?

Comment: I had a concern that you were connecting as a different user than intended, and it sounds like that is not the case.  `SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_cipher';`. If you get back a value, you do indeed have an SSL connection, you just have no assurance (per the warning) that the server is genuine. Client certificate/key/CA-file are not technically required for an SSL connection to be encrypted, but are necessary to authenticate the peers.  MySQL made things hard, with the best of intentions, by requiring them with the CLI. They are not required by technical necessity, so you may be SSL in JDBC after all.